# How to add Meteor sources for debug

Tags: intellij-idea, meteor, webstorm

I would like to be able to debug meteor itself when debugging my application (to step in meteor.js(and maybe node.js) source code if needed). How should I do that? I'm using Webstorm and debug works very well both in client and in server but I can't find information on how to add meteor source code (besides just some header files in Javascript->Libraries).

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For node side, you can use npm-inspector package. 
Check this link [npm-inspector](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Debugging)